# Angular 6 Material Tab Navigation with an auxiliary route

Tags: angular, angular-material

I have two routers set up, one being lazy-loaded and used to access sub routes for a parent route.
The goal here is to have some high-level routes which are essentially completely unrelated pages and some of those pages to have their own subrouting where tabs are used to navigate.

Child routes:

```
const dashboardRoutes = [
    {path: '', redirectTo: 'dashboard', pathMatch: 'full'},
    {path: 'dashboard', component: DashboardContainerComponent, children:[
       {path: 'home', component: DashboardComponent, outlet: 'dashboard'},
    ]
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    RouterModule.forChild(dashboardRoutes)
  ],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class DashboardRoutingModule { }
```

Parent routes:

```
const routes: Routes = [
    {path: '', redirectTo: 'dashboard', pathMatch: 'full'},
    {path: 'dashboard', loadChildren: '../dashboard/dashboard.module#DashboardModule'}
]

  @NgModule({
    imports :[
      RouterModule.forRoot(routes, {useHash: true})
    ],
    exports: [
      RouterModule
    ]
  })
export class RoutingModuleModule { }
```

This works fine when I type the path into the address bar:
`http://localhost:4200/#/dashboard/dashboard/(dashboard:home)`

However, when I attempt to use Material Tab navigation, I get: `Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'dashboard/dashboard/%28dashboard:home%29'`

In my Component I have:

```
navlinks = [
    {path: '(dashboard:home)', label: 'Home'}
]
```

html:

```
<nav mat-tab-nav-bar mat-align-tabs="center">
    <a mat-tab-link
    *ngFor="let link of navlinks"
    [routerLink]="link.path"
    routerLinkActive #rla="routerLinkActive"
    [routerLinkActiveOptions]="{exact: true}"
    [active]="rla.isActive">
    {{link.label}}
</a>
</nav>

<router-outlet name="dashboard"></router-outlet>
```

This appears to be essentially the correct thing to have, however, at some point the parentheses are likely being replaced.

I have attempted several variations such as no parentheses, slashes etc but none have produced the desired result.

Does anyone have any suggestions on what the value in my list of links should look like?

Comment: Try:`{path: './dashboard/home', label: 'Home'}`

Comment: Check this:https://angular.io/guide/router

Comment: I think you need to rewrite your route paths too. Why do you want `dashboard` to appear so many times on the URL?

Comment: I don't necessarily need dashboard to appear so many times, however, that shouldn't have an impact on whether this works or not. Thanks for the suggestion though, I'll look into simplifying the routes. In regards to the first comment, that provides me with a similar error: `Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'dashboard/dashboard/dashboard/home'`

Note that these are auxiliary routes, so you need to use the (x:y) format as far as I understand.